# Incompatible pointer types passing 'string’ (aka 'char *’) to parameter of type 'string *’ (aka [char **’)

Tags: arrays, c, command-line-arguments, cs50

I tried writing a code that receives a string of input and then changes the vowels contained, if any, to some particular numbers. I am not done yet, but I decided to test run the code before I continue but I keep getting this error. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

string replace_letter(string argv[1]);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string replace = replace_letter(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }
}

string replace_letter(string argv[1])
{

    switch(argv[1])
    {
        case a:
        printf(6);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there another error or warning from your compiler? What about `printf(6);` or `case a:`?

Comment: This code here is a perfect illustration why CS50 is such a bad class. Stay clear from any learning material from Harvard, they have no clue how to properly teach C programming.

Comment: I disagree with the statement by someone else not to learn from CS50. Overall, I think that class does a very good job of teaching C. The main reason that CS50 has a bad reputation on Stack Overflow is that it does not immediately explain what is behind the data type `string`. However, you will learn this in week 4 of CS50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the parameter of the function `replace_letter` the name `argv`. This name is misleading, because the `argv` parameter of the function `main` is an array of strings, whereas the parameter of the function `replace_letters` is supposed to be a single string.

If you change this misleading name to something more appropriate, for example `str` (which is short for "string"), then it may be clearer what is wrong in your function `replace_letter`:

```
string replace_letter(string str[1])
{

    switch(str[1])
    {
        case a:
        printf(6);
        break;
    }
}
```

In order to pass a string as a parameter to the function `replace_letter`, you should declare the parameter like this:

```
string replace_letter(string str)
```

By using

```
string replace_letter(string str[1])
```

instead, you are declaring that an **array of** strings is being passed as a parameter, and you are incorrectly implying that the length of this array is `1` (although the number `1` is ignored by the compiler in this case). This is not what you want.

When declaring an array, the number in the `[]` specifies the size of the array, whereas in a normal expression outside a declaration, the number in the `[]` specifies the index in the array that you want to access. You appear to be confusing these two meanings.

If you make the change described above and also change the forward declaration of the function accordingly, then your code should look like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

string replace_letter(string str);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string replace = replace_letter(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }
}

string replace_letter(string str)
{

    switch(str[1])
    {
        case a:
        printf(6);
        break;
    }
}
```

This fixes the error that you specified.

However, there are still other issues in the program, for example

- checking the value of `argc` only after calling `replace_letter(argv[1])`,
- writing `case a:` instead of `case 'a':`,
- writing `printf(6);` instead of `printf("6");`,
- only converting the second character of the string (`str[1]`), and
- not using a `return` statement in the function `replace_letter`, although that function is declared to return a value.

I will leave it up to you to solve the remainder of the assignment.